# mingw32-make fails in cmd due to temporary errors of non-literal type and non-trivial destructor in open CV sources

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I need to inject Open CV to Qt according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOSu-2Oju-A&list=PLohmkyszOCTDnpEsj_auXWK2m_lPTyZbK), but at the stage mingw32-make on cmd I got en error.

```
    C:/opencv/sources/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h: In constructor 'constexpr google::protobuf::internal::WrappedMutex::WrappedMutex()':
C:/opencv/sources/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h:124:29: error: temporary of non-literal type 'google::protobuf::internal::CallOnceInitializedMutex<std::mutex>' in a constant expression
   constexpr WrappedMutex() {}
                             ^
C:/opencv/sources/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h:98:7: note: 'google::protobuf::internal::CallOnceInitializedMutex<std::mutex>' is not literal because:
 class CallOnceInitializedMutex {
       ^
C:/opencv/sources/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h:98:7: note:   'google::protobuf::internal::CallOnceInitializedMutex<std::mutex>' has a non-trivial destructor
3rdparty\protobuf\CMakeFiles\libprotobuf.dir\build.make:90: recipe for target '3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1727: recipe for target '3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:164: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Should I change the destructor in the file mutex.h or should I do something else? I am newbie and already in despair.

Comment: "Should I change the destructor in the file mutex.h"  -- NOOOO. update your compiler instead

Comment: I encountered the same error, when building with Qt5.12.12. and OpenCV 4.5.5.
I working solution is to use 3.4.16 with qts Mingw73_64 compiler.
Unfortunately, I get the undefined reference error when trying to read an image afterwards follwoing the tutorial.

Comment: Undefined references got solved according to https://forum.qt.io/topic/55150/opencv-and-qt-cv-imread-only-problem/2 -> you need to add LIBS+=libopencv_imgcodecs